# Что делает функция bind?

Tags: c++

Зачем функции bind нужен ip если она связывает socket с портом.

Comment: И с конкретным ip тоже - мало ли какие они там у вас на машине...

Comment: у вас на машине может быть несколько ip-адресов и один и тот же порт можно на каждом ip использовать отдельно (и даже разными приложениями)

Comment: *биндит* конечно